# How to read data from mongodb with php

Tags: php, mongodb

i'm using mongodb and my result of find is this one

```
> db.analysis.find().pretty() 
{ "_id" : "a", "age" : [ "d" ] }
{ "_id" : "b", "age" : [ "a", "b", "e" ] }
```

Here is the query I use in php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query([]);

$rows = $mng->executeQuery("whot.analysis", $query);

$return_array = array();

   foreach ($rows as $row) {
            array_push($return_array,
                 array(
                   "_id" => "$row->_id",
                   "age" => "$row->age"
            ));
           }

$json= json_encode($return_array);

echo $json;
```

As a result

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /usr/local/nginx/html/mongo_analysis.php on line 39

Notice: Array to string conversion in /usr/local/nginx/html/mongo_analysis.php on line 39

[{"_id":"a","age":"Array"},{"_id":"b","age":"Array"}]
```

Can anyone let me know how to change the code?

i want to change Array to string..

Comment: which line is 39?

Comment: 39 line is  "age" => "$row->age"

Comment: when you remove the "" around `$row->age` the error should be gone and the complete array `$row->age` will be assigned to "age". This doesn't answer why $row->age is an array in first place, though...

Comment: Thank u sir.. i was stupid..

Comment: I woudn't be that harsh to myself... there's a reason for the (at least german) saying "4 eyes see more than 2".